# How to write test for exception

Tags: java, unit-testing, testing, mockito

I've got this method

```
       public PropertyEntity sendToApprove(Long id) throws CheckedException, NotFoundException {
        PropertyEntity entity = propertyDataService.findById(id, false);
        NotFoundException.check(entity == null, "Property not found.");
        if (entity.getStatus() == PropertyStatus.DRAFT) {
            CheckedException.check(propertyDataService.validateProperty(entity), "Please 
 apply all mandatory fields!");
            entity.setStatus(PropertyStatus.PENDING);
//            not use save method to avoid status changing to draft
            propertyDataService.saveAll(Collections.singletonList(entity));
            propertyDataService.updateMinMaxPriceAndBedBath(entity.getId());
        } else {
            throw new CheckedException("Approve from this status is not supported");
        }
        return entity;
    }
```

Need to write test if entity is null then method: send to approve throws exception NotFound.
I'm new in this testing so far I've done this

```
@ExtendWith(MockitoExtension.class)
public class PropertyControllerSendToApproveTest {

    private PropertyDataService propertyDataService = Mockito.mock(PropertyDataService.class);

    private PropertyManager propertyManager = Mockito.mock(PropertyManager.class);
    

    @BeforeEach
    public void init() throws CheckedException, NotFoundException {
        Mockito.when(propertyManager.sendToApprove(1L)).thenReturn(null);
    }

    @Test
    @DisplayName("when property is null then not found exception")
    public void testWhenPropertyIsNull() throws CheckedException, NotFoundException {
        when(propertyManager.sendToApprove(anyLong()) == null)
                .thenThrow(NotFoundException.class);
    }
 }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
@Test
@DisplayName("when property is null then not found exception")
public void testWhenPropertyIsNull() throws CheckedException, NotFoundException {
    when(propertyManager.sendToApprove(anyLong()) == null)
            .thenThrow(NotFoundException.class);
}
```

So in the test case would throw an exception as you have mentioned with the thenThrow method. You need to add

```
@Test(expected = NotFoundException.class)
```

expected means the test case expects a NotFoundException and your test throws the same

Comment: okay thanks a lot ,testing is just strange)))))) thanks

Comment: yeah make sure you remember one thing about unit testing atleast for Mockito based ones. You are always mocking an object meaning that there isnt any real instantiation, so whatever behaviour you expect from the method, you need to mock it as well as handle it for your test cases too. Unit testing is all about covering in and out of your code and checking if it works like it is expected to :)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/users/9481374/varadharajan-raghavendran thanks a lot it's helped